# Set session variable within a Snowflake procedure based on the procedure argument

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, session-variables

I have a view in Snowflake that uses session variables (date ranges) within it. I want to call the view from a procedure and define the session variables based on the arguments passed to the procedure. Unfortunately the below isn't working....any ideas?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE(DATE_FROM_a DATE, DATE_TO_a DATE)
  RETURNS TABLE()
  LANGUAGE SQL
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS 
  $$
  DECLARE
  SET DATE_FROM = :DATE_FROM_a;
  res resultset default (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM v_TEST);
  BEGIN
  return table(res);
  END;
  $$
  ;
```

Comment: Hi - just saying that something isn't working doesn't provide a lot of useful information for someone to be able to help you. Please update question to show what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and any error messages that you are seeing

Comment: Hi , can you give the defiantion of the view, some sample data and the output that you re getting/expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it's written in your test, it's not actually executing the `SET` command statement. You can move the `SET` command statement to after the BEGIN. That will set the session variable. Note that setting session variables in stored procedures is only supported when executing with callers rights.

```
create or replace table v_test (s string);

CREATE or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE(DATE_FROM_a DATE, DATE_TO_a DATE)
  RETURNS TABLE()
  LANGUAGE SQL
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS 
  $$
  DECLARE
  res resultset default (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM v_TEST);
  BEGIN
  SET DATE_FROM = :DATE_FROM_a;
  return table(res);
  END;
  $$
  ;
  
call test_procedure('2012-12-12', '2020-05-01');

select $DATE_FROM;
```

Comment: ... or they can just move "SET DATE_FROM = :DATE_FROM_a;" into BEGIN block (hopefully before the RETURN statement). I checked this question but I couldn't notice that they are trying to execute a command in DECLARE section :)

Comment: That's a simpler fix so I updated the answer.

Comment: I’m not quite seeing how this works … the problem statement is that a view is defined using session variables, and that they want to be able use a stored proc that calls the view from the procedure using the session variables.   This example shows a table created in the session, parameters sent to the stored proc, a variable set in the sproc, and a query against the table (not using any values).  Help me understand what I’m missing here …

Comment: The table creation is just a substitute placeholder to get a complete test harness. Without it, the SP will not compile because it's missing an object reference.